# Querying Ms SQL server from PHP returns invalid name

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2016

I have connected to MS SQL server successfully, but trying to copy the SQL query from SQL server to the PHP code returns invalid object.
What could I be doing wrong?

I have tried using table "Students" without using the dollar sign, also I have tried introducing an underscore to "MARINUS HIGH" but still the same error. I have alse tried the below code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE No_='A100/0011G/17' AND Password='123'";
```

Returns

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S02 [SQLSTATE] => 42S02 [1] => 208 [code] => 208 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Students'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Students'. ) )

```
$serverName = "127.0.0.1";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"MyDB", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"******" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT   No_, [Name], [Password]
FROM     [MARINAS HIGH$Students]
WHERE  (No_='A100/0011G/17') AND ([Password]='123')";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

if( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) === false) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$name = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 0);
echo $name; //maybe the name is "George"
```

Expecting to fetch from MS SQL server using PHP. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: is this your actual table name? `[MARINAS HIGH$Students]`?

Comment: On my Server Management Studio, it reads dbo.MARINAS HIGH$Students

Comment: The $sql variable returns the expected result in Management Studio

Comment: Try escaping the `$` in `[MARINAS HIGH$Students]` so it is: `[MARINAS HIGH\$Students]`

Comment: Try this way: `select * from [dbo].[#MARINAS HIGH$Students]`

Comment: Wow, @Adder, that worked for me. Thank you so so much.

Comment: and if you can, try to avoid using unusual characters in table names. It just causes complexity. Even an underscore (`_`) would be better.